# Font Awesome - When stacking icons, how can I center the second icon

Tags: css, background, font-awesome

**When stacking icons, how can I center the second icon?**

I'm trying to create a white background for a circle and a checkbox see plnkr example:

http://plnkr.co/5JM1yk6eoeAnj1VgkxXA

```
<span class="fa-stack">
  <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
</span>

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label .fa-check-circle {
  display: block;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #37B34A;
  height: 28px;
  width: 28px;
}

.fa-circle-thin {
  color: #DDDDDD;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 28px;
  width: 28px;
  text-align:center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving a `margin-left` to  `.fa-stack .fa-check-circle` will do it

```
.fa-stack .fa-check-circle {
    margin-left: 2px;
}
```

Although I think this is not the best way of doing what you're trying to do there, I think this way should be a better way of doing it: http://jsfiddle.net/7w41fboo/

**======== Update =========**

If you need to remove the white space of the background of your checked circle, you can do it with this trick. 
First exchange the `fa-check-circle` for `fa-check` like this:

HTML

```
<div class="faWhiteBg">
    <input type="checkbox">
        <label>
            <span class="fa-stack">
                <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i>
            </span>
            Unchecked
        </label>
</div>

<br />

<input type="checkbox" checked>
<label>
    <span class="fa-stack">
        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    </span>
    Checked
</label>
```

Then style your `fa-check` in your CSS

```
.fa-stack .fa-check {
    background: #37B34A;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.fa-stack {
    cursor: pointer;
}
/* The code below is a code to display the white background only for the non checked circle, if you don't want it you can remove this part of the code and remove it from your HTML as well*/
.faWhiteBg .fa-stack {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

**Here's an [online example](http://jsfiddle.net/7w41fboo/4/)**

Comment: I see I need to clarify one thing: I was trying to avoid the white outside of the circle as well, but once i set the height and width it's no longer centered.

Comment: Let me get it straight, so what you're trying to do is remove the white part outside of it and center the circle?

Comment: Looks good! I see you got the checked one working and I'm sure I can do something same thing to the unchecked one by stacking two fa-circles of different size. Thanks again!